# The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression

Tags: javascript, rest

I am trying to filter standard Calendar events via SharePoint web api and my query looks like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge  datetime'2013-01-26T22:00:00Z')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

Query doesn't work and I receive this error:

> The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression

Error Details:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression."},"innererror":{"message":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression.","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.CheckFieldRefUsage(SPField field, FieldRefUsage fieldRefUsage)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.SetFieldRef(XmlWriter writer, String fieldPath, FieldRefUsage fieldRefUsage, Action`1 attributeAction)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.SetWhereBinaryOp(XmlWriter writer, EdmParserNode parseNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.SetViewQuery(SPQuery query, XmlWriter writer, StringBuilder sb)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.BuildCamlQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder..ctor(SPList list, RESTfulQuery restQuery, Nullable`1 itemId)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollection.TryWriteAsOData(ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.Write(Object value, Uri path, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)","internalexception":{"message":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression.","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","stacktrace":""}}}}
```

Is it possible somehow to use fields type of DateTime in filter query expressions?

Update:
I found that I can do this via ListData.svc, e.g.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar?$filter=StartTime+ge+datetime'2011-11-23'
```

More details here - http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/12/rest-filter-datetime/

I tried to remove the time part from the /_api/web/ query, e.g.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge  '2013-01-26')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

But it didn't help and I got the same error.

These queries below don't work:

Query 1:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge datetime'2013-01-26T22:00:00Z')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

OR

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge '2013-01-26')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

Error:

```
The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression
```

Query 2:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge datetime'2013-01-26')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

Error:

```
The expression "( EventDate ge datetime'2013-01-26')" is not valid
```

Comment: SharePoint version please?

Comment: Did you get the answer for the above question?

Comment: Your comment is correct, this worked for me for date range.

**/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar?$filter=(StartTime+le+datetime'myStartDate' and EndTime+ge+datetime'myEndDate')**

Where myStartDate and myEndDate are the variables for the current item's eventDate and endDate. This returns only items that take place at the same time as the current item.

Comment: How does the ListData.svc version know what Calendar to look for? I tried doing this and I get an error saying "Resource not found for the segment 'Calendar'"

Answer (score 1):

You actually have the answer in your question. In your update you show:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar?$filter=StartTime+ge+datetime'2011-11-23'
```

Notice the string with the date is prefaced by **datetime**. You just need to do the same thing in the query you are trying to write.

http://www.odata.org/documentation/overview#AbstractTypeSystem

Comment: no, it doesn't work for /_api/web query. added these queries to my question. thank you!