# Filtering Calendar Items Using REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, filter, query

I'am trying to get calendar items and filtering by EventDate and EndDate fields using rest api. DateTime field filtering works fine on other lists but I can not filter calendar items by EventDate and EndDate. Exact same issue with [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/6c0b65cd-c3e0-4761-a70e-2235736ce0cc/cant-use-eventdate-or-enddate-when-filtering-calendar-items-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

At powershell I'm getting this error when I try to filter by EventDate field

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Is there anybody know how to solve this without using ListData.svc?

This works great

```
$restUrl="http://www.myspportal.com/sites/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RestTestCalendar')/items?`$select=*&`$filter=Title eq 'test'"
$response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -Headers @{ "Accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose" } 
$response=$response -creplace '"ID":','"ListItemID":' 
$items = $response| ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($item in $items.d.results)
{
write-host "Title `t-->" $item.Title
}
```

but this is not working

```
$restUrl="http://www.myspportal.com/sites/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RestTestCalendar')/items?`$select=*&`$filter=Title eq 'test' or EventDate eq datetime'2018-05-09T09:00:00Z'"
$response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -Headers @{ "Accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose" } 
$response=$response -creplace '"ID":','"ListItemID":' 
$items = $response| ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($item in $items.d.results)
{
write-host "Title `t-->" $item.Title
}
```

Getting this error

[image]

Also logs say this

```
The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression
```

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: Updated question. :)

Comment: Try This $restUrl="http://www.myspportal.com/sites/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RestTestCalendar')/items?`$select=*&`$filter=Title eq 'test' or EventDate eq datetime'[uri]::EscapeDataString(2018-05-09T09:00:00Z)'"

Comment: Thank you for your response. But unfortunately it's not working. Getting same error.

Comment: can you try using the url as `http://www.myspportal.com/sites/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RestTestCalendar')/items?$select=*&$filter=((Title eq 'test') or (EventDate eq datetime'2018-05-09T09:00:00Z'))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/the-field-eventdate-of-type-datetime-cannot-be-used-in-the-query-filter-expr)

Comment: Thank you for your response Gautam, I tried but still same error. I've updated question with logs. I guess SharePoint does not support calendar filter with EventDate.

Comment: Try this http://www.myspportal.com/sites/Dev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/RestTestCalendar?$filter=((Title eq 'test') or (EventDate eq datetime'2018-05-09T09:00:00Z'))

Answer (score 2):

Use SharePoint Manager to verify the value for the EventDate ("Start Time") field and check its Filterable property is set to false, and this is what is causing the error message to be returned.

Create a DateTime column from scratch and named it "Testdate" and it should work:

```
  http://www.myspportal.com/sites/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RestTestCalendar')/items?$select=*&$filter=Testdate eq datetime'2018-05-09T09:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (notice StartTime is used instead of EventDate)

```
function getEntries() {
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar?$select=Id,Title,StartTime,EndTime&$filter=StartTime ge datetime'2018-07-01'",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    call.success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#ResultsDiv").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            var item = data.d.results[i];
            $("#ResultsDiv").append(item.Title + "<br/>" + item.StartTime + "<br/><br/>");
        }
    });
    call.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error retrieving items: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```